# How to close jQuery dialog box with Iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I created a `div` for a dialog box and loaded an `iframe` inside the `div`.

My problem is I am not able to close the dialog box clicking a button from within the `iframe` with an aspx page.

I tried the code below. It is working if I use an `iframe` directly as a dialog box instead of a `div`, but it will create other issues for resize / dragging dialog box and `iframe`.

```
window.parent.$('#divdialog').dialog('close');
```

Appreciate a feasible solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys.. Finally I got solution.

Here is the code used in iframe:-

`window.parent.CloseDialog();`

Here is the code used in parent page:-

```
var divdialog = $('#divdialog'); divdialog.dialog('destroy');
        divdialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height: 310,
            width: 570,title: "Look Up",
            modal: true,
            open: function () {$('#testframe').attr("src", strValue);
            $('#testframe').height($(this).height()-5);       $('#testframe').width($(this).width()-10);         
                },
            close: function (e) {
                $('#divdialog').remove();
                },
            resizable: true,
            resize: function() { $('#divdialog iframe').hide(); },
            resizeStop: function() { $('#divdialog iframe').show(); 
            $('#divdialog iframe').height($(this).height()-10);  
            $('#divdialog iframe').width($(this).width()-10); } ,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            draggable:true
        })

function CloseDialog()
{
    $('#divdialog').dialog('close'); return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to reach elements that is on the main page from the iframe code you need to use the `window.top.document` on the selectors as:

```
jQuery("#ElementID", window.top.document)
```

with that parameter the selector is search the page that contains the iframe, so you can close your dialog box.

and your code will be:

```
$('#divdialog', window.top.document).dialog('close');
```

Comment: window.top.document works fine if I use iframe as dialog box since I am using div as dialogbox here I am getting only iframe element.Any other idea?

Comment: @Sush I am not follow you. Can you tell me that: Where the javascript runs, where the dialog lives ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the solution for this and posted the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add some buttons to the dialog.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ 
buttons: [ { text: "Ok", click: function() { $( this ).dialog( "close" ); } ] 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I presume this will work,  but i need to close the dialog box from the page which is loaded inside the iframe.